# Frontpage is a menu item...title won't change

Tags: 7

When I access site via / or /fp, I always get 'Home', this only happens for the home page...How can I change the title?

```
$items['fp'] = array(
    'title' => 'Front Page',
    'page callback' => 'rocdocs_main_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'title callback' => 'rocdocs_main_view_title',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);


function rocdocs_main_view_title()
{   
    return 'THIS IS A TEST';
}
```

Comment: Is this drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: This is drupal 7

Comment: In your code. The variable $items: Do you have a "return $items" at the end or is it not part of a function. Hard to see what's going on. Also what file do you have this in? your template.php file? or a custom module?

Comment: go with @ChrisJ.Lee here... its easy to miss the return in hook_menu()... also suggest you could check the logs for page not found for the request if thats the case...

Answer (score 0):

Just deactivate the predefined menu link and add a new one - use

```
<front>
```

as path.

In Drupal 7 and 8 go to

```
Home > Administration > Structure > Menus > Main menu > Add link
```

Drupal 7
[image: Drupal 7]

See tooltip for details (using [Rubik Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/rubik))
[image: See tooltip for details]