# How to change front page title?

Tags: 7

The front page title in the menu is Home or Startseite in german. I would like to give it another name. How can I do this?

The question is asked multiple times over the internet [(fore example here)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16353/frontpage-is-a-menu-item-title-wont-change) but no clear answer... Thank you

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1268204)? Is there what you need?

Comment: Yes I did, but i hoped there is a slimmer solution. I'll try it out and post here, if i don't get anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by "slimmer" and what's wrong with using settings page?

Comment: The provided link contains two answers. One referring to the module Page Title which i considered being to much. The other answer was refering to: /admin/settings/page-title which did not work or I didn't understand. The mentioned link is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deactivate the predefined menu link and add a new one - use

```
<front>
```

as path.

In Drupal 7 and 8 go to

```
Home > Administration > Structure > Menus > Main menu > Add link
```

Your German version will say something like

```
Startseite > Verwaltung > Struktur > Menüs > Hauptmenü > Hinzufügen
```

Drupal 7
[image: Drupal 7]

See tooltip for details (using [Rubik Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/rubik))
[image: See tooltip for details]

Drupal 8 (German version)
[image: Drupal 8 (German version)]

Comment: Perfect! I was not even necessary to add a new menu link. I could edit the existing one. 
In the end i will create the site in spanish. Just because of thinking that the page should support multiple languages, It looks like it would be hard to have the menu in different languages not? I see that it would be possible to create multiple menu's and the content is assigned to a language. But best practice to tie everything together one would have to read about. But thats another question :).

Comment: I made two multi-language sites one with two languages, one with three. I used menu translations at first, but I was better off making one menu Item in every single language rather than using the translate function - since you can have different orders and other stuff that way.